# Get `one_of` specific items in SPAQRL

Tags: sparql, rdf, wikidata

I use Wikidata as example. The following works ([test it](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%3Fname%20%3FnameLabel%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%20%20wd%3AQ1339%20wdt%3AP735%20%3Fname.%0A%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22%5BAUTO_LANGUAGE%5D%22.%20%7D%0A%7D)):

```sql
SELECT ?name ?nameLabel
WHERE
{
  wd:Q1339 wdt:P735 ?name.
  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

Now, suppose I have several items, e.g. `wd:Q1339`, `wd:Q76428` and `wd:Q57487`.

I want to construct a similar query but applied to exactly those items. If there was a magical `one_of` property (similar to `a`, which is a shortcut to `rdf:type` ), something like the following would be a solution (wrong pseudo-syntax):

```sql
SELECT ?name ?nameLabel
WHERE
{
  ?person one_of (wd:Q1339, wd:Q76428, wd:Q57487).
  ?person wdt:P735 ?name.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```

Question: How can I construct a query which yields the results?

(It should preferably be applicable not only to Wikidata.)

Comment: https://w.wiki/4nzt

Comment: your "one of" is called `VALUES` in SPARQL 1.1 - search for "inline data in SPARQL": https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#inline-data

Comment: indeed ,one could also apply a `FILTER` on the `?resource` variable - the keyword `IN` would be your friend, though it might be less efficient of the query optimizer is not possible to interpolate the filter

Comment: Thank you both @StanislavKralin @ UninformedUser for your helpful answers. From a semantic viewpoint it would imho make sense to add this information as an answer instead of a comment as the former can be accepted and upvoted which lets search algorithms better classify this question. So if anybody is willing to turn theses comments into an answer please do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning the comments from @Stanislav Kralin and @UninformedUser into an answer:

The desired keyword to assert identity of items is `VALUES`, see the example:

```
SELECT ?person ?name ?nameLabel
WHERE
{
  VALUES ?person {wd:Q1339 wd:Q76428 wd:Q57487}
  ?person wdt:P735 ?name.

  SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
}
```